# Two definitions of the strong Markov property

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

In Durrett's textbook, the strong Markov property is defined as follows:

For every bounded and measurable $\varphi$ and stopping time $N$:
$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi\circ\theta_N|\mathcal{F}_N)=\mathbb{E}_{X_N}(\varphi) \tag{1}$$

But I think the strong markov property *should* be:
$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X_N,X_{N+1},\cdots)|\mathcal{F}_N)=\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X_N,X_{N+1},\cdots)|X_N) \tag{2}$$
for every bounded and measurable $\varphi$.

I want to deduce (2) from (1).

---

**update:**

First I suppose $\varphi=\varphi(\omega_0,\omega_1,\cdots)$ in (1)

then $$\mathbb{E}_{X_N}(\varphi) =\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb{E}(\varphi(\omega_0,\omega_1,\cdots)|X_0=k)1_{\{X_N=k\}}\overset{\text{time homogeneous}}{=}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\mathbb{E}(\varphi(\omega_N,\omega_{N+1},\cdots)|X_N=k)1_{\{X_N=k\}}=\mathbb{E}(\varphi(\omega_N,\omega_{N+1},\cdots)|X_N)$$
so we have:
$$\mathbb{E}(\varphi(\omega_N,\omega_{N+1},\cdots)|\mathcal{F}_N)=\mathbb{E}(\varphi(\omega_N,\omega_{N+1},\cdots)|X_N)$$

---

the reasoning above is right or not ?

Comment: Use `\tag{1}` for equation numbers.

Comment: Hello. How do you take the first equality in the update? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the conditional expectation (with respect to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X_N$) in $(1)$ and use the tower property.

Comment: I updated my post,I didn't take the conditional expectation,is there something wrong?

Comment: @user166445 Looks fine...